# Function returns "None" (not using any fancy functions in the code)

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, output

I am writing a game using loops and I haven't defined any functions in my code, but only using basic ones like print(). My code itself does exactly what it's supposed to do, but it throws in a `None` where the user is supposed to give input to the code.

```
while loca == 22:
    if (lever=="back") and (dial=="red"):
        print("congratlations! You have won the game!")
        play=input(print("Would you like to play again? Type 'Y' for yes and 'N' for no."))
        while play in ["yes","y","Y","Yes"]:
            loca = 1
            play="reset"
        while play in ["no","n","N","No"]:
            print("Thanks for playing!")
            quit()
        while (not play == "reset"):
            while (not play == ["no","n","N","No"]) and (not play == ["yes","y","Y","Yes"]):
                play=input(print("Sorry, I didn't understand. Please enter 'Y' for yes, or 'N' for no."))
    else:
        print("Hmm.. You don't quite have the right combination yet!")
```

I know the `quit()` is a function, but I also tried the code with it removed and it still returned a `None`. I have never had this problem with other programs I wrote that used the same function I am using in this code.

For this assignment, we are supposed to implement the quit function into the code, or some variation of it but we haven't learned about a `return` for functions (this code isn't supposed to have any author defined functions) and it seems that the only answer I can find online is to do with a `return`. I thought I would try my luck here and maybe it is just something small that I am missing.

Answer (score 3):

The `print` function returns `None`, which you're then passing to `input`, remove the calls to `print`, since `input` already takes care of printing the string passed.

Instead of:

```
play=input(print("Would you like to play again? Type 'Y' for yes and 'N' for no."))
```

Use:

```
play=input("Would you like to play again? Type 'Y' for yes and 'N' for no.")
```

Comment: Oh wow, how did I not see that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The line where you create the variable `play`. You misuse the input function the prompt you write in the function already is displayed for the user. However by putting in `print()` you return none.

That line should be:

`play = input("Would you like to play again? Type 'Y' for yes and 'N' for no.")`

P.S. you should try and conform to the PEP 8 - python style guide